# python bottle server does not work on Linux

Tags: linux, bottle

I have problem running python bottle server on linux. I installed the python and bottle on my linux box.  I ran a simple testPort.py program.

It started successfully:

```
$ sudo python ~/bottle-0.11.6/bottle-0.11.6/test/testPort.py 
Bottle v0.11.6 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://onpoint.stanford.edu:1008/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.
```

But when I used google chrome to access it: http://onpoint.stanford.edu:1008

I got the message `the webpage is not available.` Can anyone help me on this?

I checked the server, there is no activities.

Here is my linux version:

```
webmc@onpoint:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.04
Release:        13.04
Codename:       raring
```

I used the following command to check if the port is open. It seems it did open:

```
webmc@onpoint:~$ sudo netstat --tcp --udp --listening --program
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 localhost:6010          *:*                     LISTEN      59035/10        
tcp        0      0 localhost:5914          *:*                     LISTEN      46633/Xvnc      
tcp        0      0 localhost:6011          *:*                     LISTEN      53146/1         
tcp        0      0 *:46843                 *:*                     LISTEN      46694/smpd      
tcp        0      0 localhost:5915          *:*                     LISTEN      47007/Xvnc      
tcp        0      0 localhost:6012          *:*                     LISTEN      45889/7         
tcp        0      0 localhost:5916          *:*                     LISTEN      52254/Xvnc      
tcp        0      0 *:36349                 *:*                     LISTEN      54825/mpiexec   
tcp        0      0 localhost:6013          *:*                     LISTEN      46157/9         
tcp        0      0 *:3389                  *:*                     LISTEN      40078/xrdp      
tcp        0      0 localhost:5917          *:*                     LISTEN      61999/Xvnc      
tcp        0      0 *:microsoft-ds          *:*                     LISTEN      1401/smbd       
tcp        0      0 localhost:5918          *:*                     LISTEN      56300/Xvnc      
tcp        0      0 localhost:5919          *:*                     LISTEN      36383/Xvnc      
tcp        0      0 localhost:5920          *:*                     LISTEN      41164/Xvnc      
tcp        0      0 *:39396                 *:*                     LISTEN      54835/MATLAB    
tcp        0      0 *:43333                 *:*                     LISTEN      54830/MATLAB    
tcp        0      0 *:51112                 *:*                     LISTEN      54837/MATLAB    
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         *:*                     LISTEN      1974/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 *:netbios-ssn           *:*                     LISTEN      1401/smbd       
tcp        0      0 *:60591                 *:*                     LISTEN      54828/MATLAB    
tcp        0      0 onpoint.Stanford.E:1008 *:*                     LISTEN      7064/python
```

Here is my testport.py:

```
from bottle import Bottle, run, template

app = Bottle()

@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

run(app, host='onpoint.stanford.edu', port=1008)
```

Comment: Did you also navigate to http://onpoint.stanford.edu:1008/hello ?

Comment: Yes, I did do onpoint.stanford.edu:1008/hello and it gave me "the web page is not available" error. Any hint?

Comment: You might do `debug=True` to see if there are any errors.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comments. I put "debug=True" in run function. But I did not get any additional output after starting the server.Here is the only output after starting the server:webmc@onpoint:~/bottle-0.11.6/bottle-0.11.6/test$ sudo python testPort.py 
[sudo] password for webmc: 
Bottle v0.11.6 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://onpoint.stanford.edu:1008/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.

Comment: I tried "telnet localhost 80" on it and it worked(an apache web server is running on port 80 and it worked), but I tried "telnet localhost 1008"(bottle server), it gave me "unable to connect to remote host:connection refused". I tried "telnet onpoint.stanford.edu 1008" and the command works fine. So I assume the port of 1008 is opened correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a hostname problem.  Try:

```
run(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=1008)
```

Then hit:

```
http://127.0.0.1:1008/hello
```

---

N.B., If you're hitting this server from another machine, you may also have to open a hole in your firewall.  (If you want help with that you should probably open a new question, since it's truly a separate issue.)

Comment: i also faced problem like that try with localhost

Comment: Hi, I think I have to write the machine name since I need to access it from other machine by http. I think it may be firewall issue. The port seems open. I tried iptables command, but not working.

Comment: Want to clarify, it seems it works on localhost, but not from remote.

Comment: Ah, I see.  So your bottle problem is resolved, but it seems you now have a (separate) machine access problem to solve.  You may want to check your firewall settings, among other things.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on an Amazon EC2 instance, and changing from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` did not work for me.

To make it work, I had to use to the real IP address of my machine, as it appears on the `ifconfig` command.